# PHP ajax show posts when i click post

Tags: php, sql, ajax

i want to make a post form and display the post i made on the list bellow the form. Here is my code. The problem is that when i click the post button the post is stored in the database BUT i have to refresh the page to show the post i did underneath.

```
<form method="post" id="form_wall">
    <textarea name="content" id="content" class="form-control" placeholder="Share any thing what's in your mind"></textarea>
    <br>
    <div align="right">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" value="Post" />
     </div>
</form>

<h4>Latest POst </h4>
<br>
<div id="website_stuff"> </div>
            
</div>
</div>
</html>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

  load_stuff();

  function load_stuff()
  {
    $.ajax({
      url:"load_stuff.php",
      method:"POST",
      success:function(data)
      {
        $('#website_stuff').html(data);
      }
    })
  }
  $('#form_wall').on('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    if ($.trim($('#content').val()).length == 0)
    {
      alert("Please write something");
      return false;
    }
    else
    {
      var form_data = $(this).serialize();
      $.ajax({
        url:"insert.php",
        method:"POST",
        data: form_data,
        success:function(data)
        {
          if(data == 'done')
          {
            $('#form_wall')[0].reset();
            load_stuff();
          }
        }
      })
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

here is my `insert.php` code that I call when I hit the post button

```
<?php

include('database_connection.php');

if(isset($_POST["content"]))
{
    $query = "INSERT INTO content (user_id, description) VALUES (:user_id, :description)";
    var_dump($query);
    $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute(
        array(
            'user_id' => $_SESSION['user_id'],
            'description' => $_POST["content"]
            )
        );
        $result = $statement->fetchAll();
        if(isset($result))
        {
            echo 'done';
        }
}


?>
```

Here is the `load_stuff.php`

```
<?php

include('database_connection.php');
include('function.php');

if(isset($_SESSION["user_id"]))
{
    $output = '';
    $query = "SELECT content.content_id, content.user_id, content.description, user_details.user_name FROM content
                INNER JOIN user_details
                ON user_details.user_id = content.user_id
                ORDER BY content_id DESC;
                ";
    
    $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute();
    $result = $statement->fetchAll();
    
    
    $total_rows = $statement->rowCount();
    if($total_rows > 0)
    {
        foreach($result as $row)
        {
            $like_button ='';
            if(!is_user_has_already_like_content($connect, $_SESSION["user_id"], $row["content_id"]))
            {
              $like_button = '<button type="button" name="like_button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs like_button" data-content_id="'.$row["content_id"].'">Like</button>';  
            }
            $count_like = count_content_like($connect, $row["content_id"]);
            $output .='
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h3 class="panel-title"> By '.$row["user_name"].'</h3>
                               <button type="button" name="total_like" id="total_like" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs">'.$count_like.' Like</button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                '.$row["description"].'
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-footer" align="right">
                                '.$like_button.'
                            </div>
                        </div>';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $output = 'Nobody has share nothing';
    }
    echo $output;
}


?>
```

Comment: What's the difference between the two codes you posted?

Comment: You need to show the post in the JavaScript code in the client.

Comment: I added the form i call with the script

Comment: Looks like the problem may be with `load_stuff.php`

Comment: If you post a message and then, once it's completed, jump into the console and run `load_stuff()` from there does it update the page correctly?

Comment: @John show us your `load_stuff.php` code because the problem is here.

Comment: @KUMAR here is the `load_stuff.php`

Comment: Your first HTML has lots of problems. Fix those first.